# Advanced Angular @HostListener - Logging clicks for all elements within parent component (from child)

Tags: javascript, angular, events, event-handling

I want to keep the logic for a child component inside of it. However the event itself is when a click occurs from its parent component down.

child.component.ts

```
@HostListener('document:click', ['$event']) onClick(event: MouseEvent) {

  // get the parent component tag
  const parentComponent = this.eRef.nativeElement.parentNode.parentNode;

  for (let i = 0, j = parentComponent.length; i < j; i++) {
    if (event.target == parentComponent[i]) {
        console.log(parentComponent[i]);
    }
  }
```

I've tried many things to iterate through the node list and compare the click event.target to see if the click was inside `parent` or outside but I can't seem to iterate the nodeList and don't understand why.

I've tried many other things as well here at the repro [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/hostlistener-dom-traveral?file=src/app/child/child.component.ts).

Perhaps there is a much better way to watch for clicks outside/inside this component's parent? Also, I don't want to move the click logic to the parent, the logic doesn't belong there unless it has to be.

FIXED: The StackBlitz has been updated with all my research on traversing the DOM with elementRef.
Also @Ritchie looped through the nodeList properly and got it to work that way.

Comment: Why can't you just put the @HostListener on the parent and pass the flow to the child via @Input? The handling logic can stay in the child.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `target` property of the `MouseEvent` to check which component was clicked and compare it with the parents node name.

```
@HostListener('document:click', ['$event.target']) onClick(event) {
    const parentEl = this.eRef.nativeElement.parentNode.tagName;

    const path = [];
    let currentElem = event;
    while (currentElem) {
      path.push(currentElem.tagName);
      currentElem = currentElem.parentElement;
    }
    console.log('Clicked inside parent: ', path.includes(parentEl));
}
```

[Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/hostlistener-dom-traveral-js61mb?file=src/app/child/child.component.ts)

Comment: Close! But that's only if they've actually clicked the specific parent component. What about ANY element within the parent. (including elements within this child component) This is why I grabbed the parent's nodes and was trying to loop through comparing every element with the clicked element.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your question. I've updated my answer. I've added a loop to go through all the parent elements and check if it contains the specified element.

Comment: Ok, so I set your solution up in the stackblitz. It also cannot loop through as you anticipated.

Comment: I've forked your Stackblitz example and the behaviour seems to be working as you described: https://stackblitz.com/edit/hostlistener-dom-traveral-js61mb?file=src/app/child/child.component.ts Can you tell me what is not working correctly?